# Rcpp, Rtools, and cygwin: failing to install Rcpp

Tags: r, installation, cygwin, rcpp

First try, within cygwin with R 3.1.3 installed:

```
>PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

In R:

```
>install.packages("Rcpp",repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

yields an error

```
[...]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -licuuc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -licui18n
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'Rcpp.dll' failed
make: *** [Rcpp.dll] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp’
```

So I try installing Rtools 3.2. As instructed for cygwin install, I don't install cygwin's dll that are included in Rtools. Then

```
>PATH=/cygdrive/c/Rtools/bin:/cygdrive/c/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin:$PATH
```

which, in R, yields a silent non-zero status exit when trying to do the installation

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.11.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2352221 bytes (2.2 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 2.2 MB


The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp71eoxd/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

Verbose mode is not more informative. I searched a long time, but I am at a loss now. Somebody has an idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you in windows or linux? If in linux, why are you using cygwin?

Comment: I don't think cygwin even exists in linux, since it basically emulates it. To answer your question, I using windows 7.

Comment: so you have a usr/lib/... directory structure in windows?

Comment: Using cygwin, yes. It is a unix env emulator.

Comment: The Rtools manual recommends **NOT** installing cygwin on top of Rtools. Rtools contains a kernel of cygwin command in its installation. ConEmu is a decent terminal emulator. You could use that instead.

Comment: I know, I was just hoping for an easy hack out... Looks like I will have to migrate my whole environement... Or use a vm

Comment: You can use R on Windows, including from Cygwin shells.  But R still needs its msys/mingw based environment, so you have to be careful with PATH etc.  It is doable.  But there are easier environments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting frustrated dealing with the same errors. In the Cygwin installation 'Select Packages' window, search for each of these libraries and install them. For example: pcre, lzma, bz2, ... I was finally able to compile after installing all of these.

Comment: This is the solution. Install the -devel versions of all the missing libraries. The -licuuc -licui18n are both found in libicu-devel. The others are obvious. Thanks @bejota!

Comment: hello, I would like to validate, but I don't have the environment readily available to try for the moment. Trusting @dk, I validate the answer for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is not supported by R itself, and was never supported.

*Edit exactly five years later:*  As someone just saw fit to downvote this answer once more, allow me to quote [Section C.7 of the *R Installation and Administration* manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Cygwin)

> C.7 Cygwin
>
> The 32-bit version never worked well enough to pass R’s make check, and residual support from earlier experiments was removed in R 3.3.0.
>
> The 64-bit version was never supported.

I have little more to add. I just re-stated what R Core says about their own software in their own manual.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a specific reason to use 3.1.3, update your R to the latest version (3.2.1).

Many packages don't even have Windows binaries compiled for anything but the most recent R release, so 99% of the time, that solves the issue.

If all you're trying to do is to install `Rcpp` try:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", type='source')
```

Comment: 3.1.3 is the current version in cygwin_setup. I have to migrate my setup on an off-line device afterward. I would really prefer to minimize the hassle

Comment: And rtools 3.2 is supposed to be the right version for R 3.1.x